# VBA excel variable referencing for a value

Tags: vba, cell, offset

I'm still getting to grips with VBA and have an issue with something I'm trying to do and was hoping i can get some help. (sorry if it doesn't make much sense, I don't have the lingo).

This part of the code is where I need it to put a value in the last cell on col A from col I (row dependant of my variable).

```
Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("I" & RowCount)
```

If i replace the variable `"RowCount"` with `"1"` it gives me what I want. I have used the same wording for `"Range("I" & RowCount)"` multiple times with in the macro but for some reason doesn't like it in this...

Any help?

Comment: Please include more of the surrounding code and give the exact error message you are receiving for that line. And are you trying to put the last value from column I into the next free row in column A (after the existing end point) ?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and inspected the value of RowCount?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: the issue was RowCount at that moment was zero. thanks for your help!